# To avoid border highlighting in mat-selection-list component

Tags: css, angular, angular-material

I am using `mat-selection-list` component in my project.I am displaying some names as shwon in below image:

[image]

I wonder, **Why the border is highlighting on clicking scroll-bar as shown in above image,** How can i avoid the `border in the background`:

**HTML**

```
 <mat-selection-list>
   <mat-list-option *ngFor="let player of Players">
     <a mat-list-item><span>{{ player }}</span> </a>
   </mat-list-option>
 </mat-selection-list>
```

**CSS**

```
 mat-selection-list{
 position:relative;
 margin-top:-20.5px;
 width:100%;
 height:80vh;
 overflow-y: scroll;
}
::ng-deep.mat-pseudo-checkbox{
 display: none !important;
}
```

**TS**

```
  import {Component,ViewChild} from '@angular/core';

  @Component({
     selector: 'list-selection-example',
     styleUrls: ['list-selection-example.scss'],
     templateUrl: 'list-selection-example.html',
   })

  export class ListSelectionExample {
       Players: string[] = ['Sachin Tendulkar', ........ 'Anil Kumble'];
     }
```

The [DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/mat-select-list-hp5yr4?file=app%2Flist-selection-example.ts):

Comment: set `outline:none`

Comment: Its working fine in `stackblitz` but not in my project.

Comment: This is default behavior of angular. Its for accessibility feature. Whenever a popup or snackbar or any other overlay layout added the first element get selected as focus just to make the Tab button work. To disable it in your case mark tabindex="-1"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's due to a CSS property called `outline`. To remove this, just add this line to your CSS class:

```
mat-selection-list {
   outline: none;
}
```

Comment: Its working fine in `stackblitz` but not in my project.

Comment: try by putting !important property. Ex:  outline: none !important;

Comment: I have tried `!important` property also

Comment: Check if really update your code after adding this property, i mean spect the element.

Comment: I inspected it's not updated, means the `outline property`

Comment: Try to use one of this three property or all together
`outline-style:none;`
`box-shadow:none;`
`border-color:transparent;`

if any of this doesn't works, try to apply outline in the :focus